# No module named selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, quora

I am stuck with the issue where I am thrown the following Selenium error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 4, in <module>
    from quorapy import QuoraPy
  File "C:\Users\Farath Shba\Downloads\QuoraPy-master\quorapy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .quorapy import QuoraPy
  File "C:\Users\Farath Shba\Downloads\QuoraPy-master\quorapy\quorapy.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .login_util import login_user
  File "C:\Users\Farath Shba\Downloads\QuoraPy-master\quorapy\login_util.py", line 5, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ImportError: No module named selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains
```

Can someone help me out from this error, please?

*PS: This is from the Github Repo, https://github.com/socialbotspy/QuoraPy where I am trying to run the python script, quickstart.py.*

Comment: Did you install Selenium?

Comment: please try `pip install selenium` and try running the script again.

Comment: I did installed selenium already. But still the issue is popping up. Btw, I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing it this way below? It works for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

You can add `as AC` at end to be able to call action chains with just AC:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
```

Example:

```
AC(driver).[actions here]
```

Comment: Hm, just a check - what should I substitute driver as?

Sorry to sound a noob.

Comment: driver is the variable you declare the webdriver under. Eg. driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: you can name it whatever you like, but typically people name the variable 'driver', sometimes 'browser', 'dr' and so on.

Comment: Got it - let me try it out first Alichino.

Comment: Had any luck? ;-)

Comment: @Alichino - Sorry to bother you here with an unrelated matter. Could you please reply to my comment on your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932061/how-do-i-select-svg-with-id ? SO is not letting me tag you there with @ comment. Thank you !